# @Async via proxy classes is creating an exception in Spring 3.2

Tags: java, spring, cglib, spring-scheduled

I seem to have come up with a problem.

I have a class

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class MyClass extends BaseClass {

....
...
 @Async
 public void doSomething() {
 ....   
 }
....
}
```

and a Spring Config that contains

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.company.project" />
<task:annotation-driven executor="taskExecutor"/>
<task:executor id="taskExecutor" pool-size="10" queue-capacity="10" />
```

and in some part of the code i have

```
BaseClass bean = springBeans.getBean(MyClass.class);
```

but i am getting this exception

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException: Bean named 'myClass' must be of type [com.company.project.MyClass], but was actually of type [$Proxy19]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:361)
```

I can understand its a proxy class, but not sure why Spring is not allowing the Proxy to be converted.

I have the cglib 2.2 no dep on the class path, along with the Spring 3.2 core libs.

can anyone point to any clues as to fixing this ?

In short, i want a method to be Async when called.

Comment: Can you get it from the ApplicationContext via `#getBean(BaseClass.class)` or `#getBean("myClass")`?  How about `@Autowired` to `MyClass` somewhere?

Comment: I copy pasted your code and it works fine. I used a `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` for the context.

Comment: Also, assigning to a variable of type `BaseClass`, you'll have to cast it to call the `@Async` method.

Comment: the error is within Spring or CGLIB in how it is proxying the class.

Comment: The @Async method is called internally by the Target class, where a base class method calls an abstract method which calls it. How did you get the above code to work? What version of Spring, CGLIB, etc. Is there a special tag you used in the spring context ?

Comment: @Ben I'm using Spring 3.2.3 and CGLIB 2.2.2 as you are. Are you sure you have the `spring-tx` dependency?

Comment: I have Spring-tx-3.2.0.jar in the Web-INF/libs along with the other spring classes and cglib-nodep-2.2.2.jar

Comment: @Ben have you tried to replace the BaseClass to an interface? So MyClass implements MyInterface.

Comment: @Beccari no, i instead used executor directly instead of using the annotation.

Answer (score 3):

Since you have CGLIB, you might want to change the `@Scope` to

```
@Scope(value = "prototype", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
```

Comment: This seems to work, but as soon as it tried to cast the class in to a sub sub sub sub sub type another exception appears:  Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: $Proxy19 cannot be cast to com.company.project.AbstractClass
 at com.company.project.AbstractClass$$FastClassByCGLIB$$1db1c6f.invoke(<generated>)
 at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
 at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:698)
 at

Comment: There should be no such thing as `$Proxy19` anywhere, if you are using  CGLIB.

Comment: i have the CGLIB 2.2 in the class path, and there is.